# Parsing from web - script changes source code content?

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have been trying to parse a php generated web page(not site) for some time. I tried parsing using xpath through HTMLAgility in C# as well as PHP. At first I thought I was not parsing correctly due to incorrect values.

Later, I found that actually I am parsing it correctly. But there is a script in that page which is changing the value when loading. how, I don't know.

I am new to parsing, so here is what happening according to me:

1. I am downloading the source code of the content. The part I want to parse is somewhat like this:

   ```
   <b id="solved_b">0</b>
   ```
2. When the page loads, the script in the source code changes the value to something other than 0.
3. When I parse using xpath, the original value, i.e. 0 is parsed, instead of the script changed value.

So, how can I parse the changed value instead of the original one?

the page I am trying to parse is 
http://felix-halim.net/uva/hunting.php?id=59756

here is the snippet in HTMLAgility:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
namespace ParseFelix {
    class WebParser {
        string webUrl;

        public WebParser(string url) {

            webUrl = "http://felix-halim.net/uva/hunting.php?id=59756";

            HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument htmldoc = htmlWeb.Load(webUrl);

            var username = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/h2/i");
            var submittedStats = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id=\"submissions_b\"]");
            string content = htmldoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\exp\\felix\\parsed.txt", content);
            var acceptedStats = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id=\"solved_b\"]");
            Console.WriteLine("Username is {0}, you submitted {1} solutions, and {2} were accepted", username.InnerText, submittedStats.InnerText, acceptedStats.InnerText);

          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you are trying to do is parse javascript right?
And that is AFAIK not possible (aside from writing your own parser or using an existing one).
What you want is to read the manipulated DOM, and that is not trivial at all

Comment: can you please suggest some tutorials about how to read manipulated DOM?

Comment: Nope as mentioned before you'll have to write your own JS parser and hook up to which ever event you wan't to listen to.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler - you will see that site makes ajax queries and some values gets from json:

```
POST http://felix-halim.net/uva/service2.php HTTP/1.1
Host: felix-halim.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: lt
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://felix-halim.net/uva/hunting.php?id=59756
Content-Length: 73
Cookie: PHPSESSID=o6if4t4vqadv7ia6vbqcfcvi75
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"method":"uva2.chat_update","params":[12150,59756,"guest",3127,8744317]}
```

And response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 Apr 2011 05:32:08 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.15
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2069

[null,[["0","guest","1302842169"],["0","guest","1302793161"]<SKIPPED>
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to see what you get without javascript, nice tool is Firefox+Noscript+Firebug

Comment: Ah, I guess my guess was more or less correct. It is my 2nd day of parsing. So I need to study a bit more about this things. thanks for the helpful reply. ^_^